# "Toggle Menu: Intermittent Display Issue Upon Page Refresh – Seeking Guidance on Maintaining State Persistence without Unexpected Changes"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, framer-motion

I want to share an issue I am experiencing with my toggle menu. Every time I refresh the page, I notice that it appears and disappears intermittently. My desire is that this behavior does not occur; the toggle menu should only open when I click on the corresponding icon. Upon refreshing the page, it should not exhibit this unexpected behavior.

Project
https://github.com/jolgo1989/madesWeb

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/jolgo1989/madesWeb/main

Video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETGJOXd6z4M

```
const variants = {
  open: {
    clipPath: "circle(1200px at 50px 50px)",
    transition: {
      type: "spring",
      stiffness: 20,
    },
  },
  closed: {
    clipPath: "circle(30px at 50px 50px)",
    transition: {
      delay: 0.5,
      type: "spring",
      stiffness: 400,
      damping: 40,
    },
  },
};

const Sidebar = () => {
  // Estado para controlar si el sidebar está abierto o cerrado
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    // Componente motion.div con animación basada en el estado 'open'
    <motion.div className="sidebar" animate={open ? "open" : "closed"}>
      {/* Contenido del sidebar con animación de fondo */}
      <motion.div className="bg" variants={variants}>
        <Links />
      </motion.div>

      {/* Botón de alternancia para abrir/cerrar el sidebar */}
      <ToggleButton setOpen={setOpen} />
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

```
function TogglrButton({ setOpen }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setOpen((prev) => !prev)}>
      <svg width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 23">
        <motion.path
          strokeWidth="3"
          stroke="black"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          variants={{
            closed: { d: "M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5" },
            open: { d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5" },
          }}
        />
        <motion.path
          strokeWidth="3"
          stroke="black"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          d="M 2 9.423 L 20 9.423"
          variants={{
            closed: { opacity: 1 },
            open: { opacity: 0 },
          }}
        />
        <motion.path
          strokeWidth="3"
          stroke="black"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          variants={{
            closed: { d: "M 2 16.346 L 20 16.346" },
            open: { d: "M 3 2.5 L 17 16.346" },
          }}
        />
      </svg>
    </button>
  );
}
```

```
const variants = {
  open: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
    },
  },

  closed: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.05,
      staggereDirection: -1,
    },
  },
};

// Variantes de animación para el componente motion.a
const itemVariants = {
  open: {
    y: 0,
    opacity: 1,
  },

  closed: {
    y: 50,
    opacity: 0,
  },
};

const Links = () => {
  const items = [
    "Inicio",
    "Quienes Somos",
    "Noticias",
    "Proyectos",
    "Contactenos",
  ];

  return (
    <motion.div className="links" variants={variants}>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <motion.a
          href={`#${item}`}
          key={item}
          variants={itemVariants}
          //Componentes de framer-motion
          whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
          whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
        >
          {item}
        </motion.a>
      ))}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Links;
```

Comment: Will you update your Codesandbox link? It does not work. I'm curious if it's an [enter animation](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/##enter-animations) that's causing the issue.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/jolgo1989/madesWeb/main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

The flash you are seeing is because there is not an initial `clip-path` property set for the `.bg`. This makes it so that the page has to wait for the framer motion Javascript to apply the styles defined in your `variants`, which can take long enough for the you to see the flashing content. This can be fixed by applying a default `clip-path` property to your `.bg` class like so:

```
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999; //position y  z-index de estar tanto en el bg como button
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
    background: white;
    clip-path: circle(0px at 0px 0px);
    ...
}
```

Here is an [updated working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/jolgo1989/madesWeb/csb-j7jdjk/draft/bitter-sun?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fsidebar%2FSidebar.scss%3A15%2C18).

-------------

Original:

Add `initial={false}` to the `motion.div` with the variants like so:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  // Estado para controlar si el sidebar está abierto o cerrado
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    // Componente motion.div con animación basada en el estado 'open'
    <motion.div className="sidebar" animate={open ? "open" : "closed"}>
      {/* Contenido del sidebar con animación de fondo */}
      <motion.div className="bg" initial={false} variants={variants}>
        <Links />
      </motion.div>

      {/* Botón de alternancia para abrir/cerrar el sidebar */}
      <ToggleButton setOpen={setOpen} />
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

This will disable to mounting animation that you're seeing. You can read more about the `initial` prop it in the [Framer Motion docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/component/###initial). I've also made this [working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/jolgo1989/madesWeb/csb-4749rn/draft/amazing-edison?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fsidebar%2FSidebar.jsx%3A41%2C33-41%2C49&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00073j6qlpswnz4y%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00023j6q07cpsy3l%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00043j6qk76713dy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00063j6qvto5xuoz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40.477961688673986%252C59.522038311326014%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr2klr1g00023j6q07cpsy3l%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00013j6q9rr2htk3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2knkw700bv3j6qnai1h9bk%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A41%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A33%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A41%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A49%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fsidebar%252FSidebar.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00023j6q07cpsy3l%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr2knkw700bv3j6qnai1h9bk%2522%257D%252C%2522clr2klr1g00063j6qvto5xuoz%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00053j6qy9pzdksv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00063j6qvto5xuoz%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00053j6qy9pzdksv%2522%257D%252C%2522clr2klr1g00043j6qk76713dy%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00033j6qih25xaoo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00043j6qk76713dy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr2klr1g00033j6qih25xaoo%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

Comment: If you can notice, when the page loads, the white circle has an effect that moves towards the menu. However, when I apply initial={false}, I lose this effect. Are there any alternatives to preserve this effect without using this property?

Comment: Ah I see, I'll update my answer @JorgeLeonardo.

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo I've updated my answer with a working example that has no flash.